# Accessing Scala Type Class from Java code?

Tags: java, scala, typeclass, implicit

I have created a number of different auction implementations in Scala using type classes and ad-hoc polymorphism.

An example of a Scala implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/EconomicSL/auctions/blob/learning-typeclasses/src/main/scala/org/economicsl/auctions/singleunit/twosided/OpenBidDoubleAuction.scala).

In Scala one creates an instance of this auction as follows...

```
val google: GoogleStock = GoogleStock(tick=1)
val pricingRule = new MidPointPricingPolicy[GoogleStock]
val withDiscriminatoryPricing = OpenBidDoubleAuction.withDiscriminatoryPricing(pricingRule)
```

I would like users to be able to access the auction implementations from Java 8.

But I can not seem to figure out how to create an instance of an auction in Java. Taking this approach:

```
MidPointPricingPolicy<GoogleStock> midPointPricing = new MidPointPricingPolicy<GoogleStock>();
OpenBidDoubleAuction.DiscriminatoryPricingImpl<GoogleStock> auction = OpenBidDoubleAuction$.MODULE$.withDiscriminatoryPricing(midPointPricing);
```

works, but none of the type class contract methods are available. Specifically:

```
OpenBidDoubleAuction.DiscriminatoryPricingImpl<GoogleStock> auction2 = auction.insert(order3);
```

...yields the following compile error.

```
Error:(90, 82) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method insert(org.economicsl.auctions.singleunit.orders.LimitAskOrder<org.economicsl.auctions.GoogleStock>)
location: variable auction of type org.economicsl.auctions.singleunit.twosided.SealedBidDoubleAuction.UniformPricingImpl<org.economicsl.auctions.GoogleStock>
```

It seems that the Scala compiler generated contract methods for the type class are not available when the Java code is being compiled.  In my `build.sbt` file I have set `compileOrder := CompileOrder.ScalaThenJava` in order to make sure that these Scala gets compiled first so that these methods would be available.

Based on a suggestion from @GhostCat I used `javap` to find out that the Scala compiler generates the following `.class` file...

```
OpenBidDoubleAuction$DiscriminatoryPricingImpl$$anon$1.class
```

which contains the byte code definitions of the relevant methods.

So I guess I need to know how can I access things defined in this byte code file from Java? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't have the `implicit` keyword and doesn't know anything about implicits whatsoever. An `implicit def` to Java is just another method. So you'll have to add all the implicit conversions and implicit arguments explicitly when you call this code from Java. If you want to have an idea what that would look like, you can open up a Scala REPL and use the `//print <tab>` hint to see what your code would look like after a couple of desugarings and making implicits explicit.

For instance, given some typeclass `Foo` and implicit `FooSyntax`:

```
scala> 42.foo //print <tab>
   FooSyntax[Int](42)(Foo.fooInt).foo // : String
```

To be clear, where it says `<tab>` you have to press tab instead of typing it :)

Then if you're a bit lucky, all you have to do is convert that desugared Scala further into actual Java:

```
FooSyntax(42, Foo.fooInt()).foo();
```

If you're less lucky, you might have to add some extra `MODULE$` stuff. If you're *even less* lucky and you have to interoperate with things like structural types or intersection types, then you might have to use reflection or casting respectively.

But in general: **don't** use Scala's advanced features like typeclasses if you want to call that same code from Java. If you have to create a library that is callable from Java, then try to write (in Scala) Java-friendly wrappers around the advanced/incompatible parts.

Comment: Glad some scala expert came by ;-)

Comment: Another approach would be to re-implement the type classes using F-bounded polymorphism correct?  Would this approach be better than writing wrapper classes?

Comment: I guess it depends on your intentions. If you start out with writing a library that is specifically meant to be used from Java then you're probably best off only using features that interoperate well with Java, instead of patching on Java compatibility afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

The generic answer is: those are two different languages. The only things that are **visible** on the java side are the elements found in the **bytecode** for `OpenBidDoubleAuction`.

Thus: one potential way for you to figure "what can I use from Java": turn to [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) and inspect the byte code generated by scalac. That will tell you about all available methods and their signatures. And if you find your "enhanced" example to be too complicated for that: step back. Create a *minimal* example - a small piece of scala; for which you then carefully analyze the generated byte code.

And of course: you first of all check the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/faq/4) - you want to avoid wasting your time on something that simply isn't possible. There are various language elements that you can't use from the Java side of things.

(please note: that link is outdated, but probably good enough as starting point for your own research)

Comment: Thanks.  Any ideas of what to look for in the byte code? Does the Scala compiler generate specific boilerplate in cases such as this? Perhaps compiler generates an anonymous class that contains the methods?

Comment: And just for the record: in case you solve this puzzle, it is always fine to put up a self answer (drop me a comment then, I am curious myself, too).

Comment: the "solution" that I have come up with at present is to create Java wrappers around the Scala code.  Details are [here](https://github.com/EconomicSL/auctions/blob/learning-typeclasses/src/functional/java/org/economicsl/auctions/Sandbox.java) if you are interested (scroll down towards the bottom to find the relevant bits). The wrappers are called `JOpenBidDoubleAuction` (or similar).